# Application Proxy doesn't work in Teams Desktop Task Module due to login.microsoftonline.com auth

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams

We have a published app in the Teams App Store.

And now we're working on the update which is going to let people open their on-premises sites in the teams task window.

To achieve that we're using AAD, Enterprise application, Application Proxy and assigned users who can access the portal. We didn't add single sign-on to it.

Everything is working fine in mobile apps and in the browser app, but not working in Desktop Application.

In Desktop application we have this error:

```
Refused to display 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

How can we fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you trying to send users to this login? Via popup? Redirect?

Comment: Is is the 'Teams Task module' with the on-premise site url, that is proxied with 'Microsoft Application Proxy'. Users are being redirected to the 'login.microsoftonline.com' by the 'Microsoft Application Proxy'.

Comment: So you have an on premises application that's authenticating against Azure AD?

Comment: No, users authenticate in AAD on Application Proxy level.

Answer (score 0):

The website that you use must be iFramable.
Whatever you are trying to display in tab or task module that needs to be in valid domains of Manifest

Ensure that you adhere to the following prerequisites

Allow your tab pages to be discovered in an iFrame, using X-Frame-Options and Content-Security-Policy HTTP response headers.

Set header: Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors teams.microsoft.com *.teams.microsoft.com *.skype.com

For Internet Explorer 11 compatibility, set
X-Content-Security-Policy.

Alternately, set header X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM
https://teams.microsoft.com/. This header is deprecated but still
accepted by most browsers

Reference Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tab-requirements.

Comment: Let me try to just explain what is happening:
1. User opens Task window in Teams, basically iframe with the link (The link is made by the Microsoft Application Proxy).
2. MS Application Proxy checks if user is authenticated and if not, it redirects them to the login.microsoftonline.com.
3. User authenticates and get redirected back.
4. Application Proxy checks user is auth once again.
5. User can browse on-premise site using Application Proxy link.
We're stuck on 3, login.microsoftonline.com cannot be opened in iframe.
PS: we have login.microsoftonline.com in our bots domains list

Comment: Login pages don't render in iFrames, as a safeguard against clickjacking. Your authentication logic needs to use a method other than redirect. For example, use token-based or cookie-based authentication.